# How to get machine ip and machine name

Tags: postgresql

Below query gives server ip. But i need machine ip. Please suggest how to get machine ip and machine name.

```
select inet_client_addr();
```

I used below query to get machine name but did not work.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE client_addr = inet_client_addr()
```

Comment: `select inet_client_addr();` gives you the client IP, not server, next postgres has no tools for host resolve...

Comment: If you are using DB computer (1) + server computer (2) + client's computer (3) and need an ip of client (3), you have to resolve it on the server (2), since (1) does not has direct connection with (3). Then send the ip to DB as argument of stored procedure and work with it.

Answer (score 32):

Your question is not clear, but if you want the IP address of the database server you are connected to, you could try

```
SELECT inet_server_addr();
```

But remember that every computer has several IP addresses. If you connected to `localhost`, you will get `127.0.0.1` or `::1`, depending whether you use IPv4 or IPv6.

There is no function to figure out *all* IP addresses of the database server. If you need that, you'd have to write a function in a sufficiently powerful unrestricted language like [PL/PerlU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, i need to get the client machine ip which is connecting to the database. Hoping, i am clear now.

Comment: The same holds for `inet_client_addr`. It will give you the IP address you connected from. There is no way to get other IP addresses of the same machine within a database session. You must find the address in an external program and feed the result to the database session if you need it there.